# mySQL less than one hour

Tags: mysql

I have a created_at column as a datetime in shares table and life_time column as an integer (minutes) in status table. I want to find,

```
(created_at + life_time - CURDATE()) < 1 HOUR
```

Here is my sql :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shares AS s INNER JOIN status AS st ON s.status_id = st.id 
WHERE (s.created_at INTERVAL st.life_time MINUTE - CURDATE()) < 1 HOUR";
```

> ERROR : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'INTERVAL st.life_time MINUTE - CURDATE()) < 1 HOUR LIMIT 0,
>   25' at line 1

Status Table

[image]

Shares table

[image]

Comment: And...?  What happens?  What does explain tell you?

Comment: `< 1 HOUR` from `NOW()` ?

Comment: for example, my created_at:  2018-01-01 22:00:00 and life_time is 60 minutes and then now is 2018-01-01 22:28 ...... I sum the created_at and life_time = 2018-01-01 23:00:00 then subtract now = i take 32 minutes. If 32 minutes less then 1 hour return me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
WHERE s.created_at INTERVAL st.life_time MINUTE  > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```

I am sure what you must use > or <